# AutoCompleteTextView dropdown onScrollListener?

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

I want to hide the soft keyboard when the user starts scrolling the dropdown of my AutoCompleteTV. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679264/android-autocompletetextview-hide-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use OnTouchListener on the layout and hide the keyboard